# Как вывести ограниченное количество селектов в каждом табе

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

Есть несколько табов, в каждом из которых, скажем, 10 селектов с различными элементами (что-то вроде фильтров). Как сделать так, чтобы в каждом из табов выводилось, к примеру, только 4 первых селекта? Следующие 4 селекта появляются при нажатии на кнопку вперед и т.д. Перейти к предыдущим селектам можно с помощью кнопки, к примеру, назад. Что-то вроде пагинации.

**Обновление**

Есть, скажем, 12 li-элементов в одном ul. Как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке страницы отображались первые 5 элементов и появлялась кнопка ДАЛЕЕ. По нажатии на кнопку появляются следующие 5 элементов и, соответственно, добавляется кнопка НАЗАД. Если нажать на кнопку ДАЛЕЕ еще раз, выводяться последние 2 элемента, кнопка ДАЛЕЕ исчезает и остается только НАЗАД.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/0mrco8r8/
Обратите внимание, список слева оставлен для примера, список справа был обработан.

```
var Paginator = function (wrap) {
    this.$wrap = $(wrap);
    this.$items = this.$wrap.find('li');

    this.count = this.$wrap.data('count');
    this.prevText = this.$wrap.data('prev');
    this.nextText = this.$wrap.data('next');
    this.currentPage = 0;
    this.pages = Math.floor(this.$items.length / this.count);

    this.prevHtml = '<span class="list-paginator js-prev">' + this.prevText + '</span>';
    this.nextHtml = '<span class="list-paginator js-next">' + this.nextText + '</span>';

    this.init();
};

Paginator.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        var self = this;

        this.$wrap.on("click", ".js-prev", function () {
            self.currentPage--;
            if (self.currentPage < 0) {
                self.currentPage = 0;
            }

            self.changePage();
        });

        this.$wrap.on("click", ".js-next", function () {
            self.currentPage++;
            if (self.currentPage > self.pages) {
                self.currentPage = self.pages;
            }
            self.changePage();
        });

        this.changePage();
    },

    changePage: function () {
        this.$wrap.find(".js-prev").remove();
        this.$wrap.find(".js-next").remove();

        if (this.currentPage === 0) {
            this.$wrap.append(this.nextHtml);
        } else if (this.currentPage === this.pages) {
            this.$wrap.append(this.prevHtml);
        } else {
            this.$wrap.append(this.nextHtml);
            this.$wrap.append(this.prevHtml);
        }

        this.showItems();
    },

    showItems: function () {
        var start = this.currentPage * 5;

        this.$items.each(function (i) {
            var $this = $(this);

            if (i < start) {
                $this.hide();
            } else if (i >= start + 5) {
                $this.hide();
            } else {
                $this.show();
            }
        });
    }
};

var paginator1 = new Paginator('.js-list-1');
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, именно это я и искал)